# MS-Access/SQL split: the front-end security changes if I move it to a different folder

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, frontend, ms-access-2016

I have split my MS-Access database into a MS-Access front-end and MS-SQL back-end. The back-end is stored on a shared network drive, and I intend to install/link the front-end file on different computers. When the front-end opens in Access, the input form automatically becomes fullscreen.

[image]

Moreover, the user can still only see the input form even if it is restored down.

When the user wants to close the form, Access asks for a password if they want to see the ribbon. If they choose not to enter a password, the form and Access close. I will also disable the shift key.

However, when I simply move the front-end file to a new folder or subfolder, the security settings/active content are disabled:

[image]

At this point, the user can even close the input form without being asked for a password and access everything. My question is: is there a way to prevent the active content from being disabled by simply moving the front-end to a new location? Thank you!

Comment: What version of MS-Access is this? Are you distributing a compiled (accde) front-end or source (accdb) database?

Comment: @dbmitch Hi! When I split my file, I got the accdb. So I assume that it is not a true front-end? I am using Access 2016.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 2016, but with previous versions - or non-runtime full versions installed, the user's preferences might override your current database setting? I really am just guessing. But if you distribute a compiled front-end you'll have a lot more control

Comment: @dbmitch I used the automatic split from Access. How would you do a compiled front-end rather than the source code? Thanks!

Comment: It might be a Trust Center thing? Do they get a message about security and disabling code? If you haven't setup a new folder in the Trusted Locations, it's possible your startup code can be ignored - especially if it's an accdb file

Comment: Like I said I don't know Access 2016 - I thought that was a web app or something. Other versions will allow you to do `File | Save & Publish | Make ACCDE`

Comment: @dbmitch I forgot to ask: how do I get a trust certificate for my vba code because I keep getting trust warnings. Thank you!

Comment: You're not going to get a Trust Certificate. But you can Add your local folder to a Trusted Location in Access - at least non - Access 2016

Answer (score 0):

To do this security you have other more robust solutions for example:
1- Use Modal Popup form for your main form without all system buttons including close button and use your own "Close" button to do whatever function you need.

2- Hide the ribbon:

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

3- If you are showing popup form you can hide the entire main msaccess window by API function and pass to it ***Application.hwnd***.

Never depend on security on client computers as it can be sneaked around.
Make sure you handle all possible errors or else you end up with one user showing your code in debug mode (with .accdb files) or compile to .accde.